# Best practices for variable assignment

Tags: c#, constructor, game-engine

I'm creating a development console for a game, and would like to add Json deserialization from the console input so I can add entities to the world as I please.

I'm curious if this code sample is bad practice or not. I'm simply checking to see if the property is null. If it's null, I set it to the parameter, otherwise it gets set to itself. Are there any cases where this could cause a serious problem?

```
public class Entity
{
  public Entity(int id, float health, Vector3 location)
  {
    Init(id, health, location);
  }
  public void Init(int id, float health, Vector3 location)
  {
    Id = id;
    Health = health;
    Location = Location ?? location;
  }
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public float Health { get; set; }
  public Vector3 Location { get; set; }
}
```

Also, is there a way to do something like this in one line?

```
Location = ?? location;
```

So it doesn't have to set Location to itself when it is not null?

Comment: It can't have a location already when it's constructed.

Comment: Isn't `Vector3` a struct? If so, you won't be able to test for `null` anyway unless you declare `Vector3?` (nullable).

Comment: I don't get what you intend with `Location = Location ?? ...;` Doesn't make sense, because it's alway null at that point of execution.

Comment: Abstract, Vector3 is a class. I'm not using a game engine or I would have tagged it.

Comment: Alex Beisley, It could if it's being deserialized from a file.

Comment: If you call a constructor, a new instance is created.

Comment: If you had deserialized the object that very constructor isn't even called.

Comment: JeffRSon, typically in games-engines you will have a prefab manager that stuffs entities with predefined values. So no.

Comment: You can deserialize without calling a constructor. Non if this is part of my question.

Comment: @aj.toulan: You can't call a constructor with values already assigned, however. A new instance is created with default values. Serialization is irrelevant. There is no way for Location to have a value already, when the object is created by the constructor.

Comment: Oh yeah. I usually have an init function that I place into my constructors. I guess I should have put that as well instead of trying to keep it short. I will make the appropriate changes.

Comment: Typically the parameterless default constructor is used when deserializing. In any way - if the object exists (how ever it had been created) no constructor can be called later on.

Comment: I clearly need food in me. Sorry for the confusion everyone. :3

Comment: In this case, if they're calling Init, it's possible for Location to be null, but it's still somewhat bad practice to have a parameter which may be arbitrarily ignored. It's the Principle of Least Surprise. From the contract, the method appears to take something. If you intend for it to sometimes not, you should find a different way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in a constructor, this isn't necessary, because `Location` will always be null (or `default(Vector3)`) at the time you execute the code. So you can just write:

```
public Entity(int id, float health, Vector3 location)
{
  Id = id;
  Health = health;
  Location = location;
}
```

In other cases where the value of `Location` isn't known at the time the code is executed, this is short enough:

```
Location = Location ?? location;
```

But personally, I prefer the more explicit syntax most of the time:

```
if (Location == null)
{
    Location = location;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I just wasn't sure if there was some other shorthand for this.